# D3: How to define responsibility text?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm newbie with D3 and I don't know why text-anchor doesn't work correctly. I have developed a multiple bar chart. And the text that I put over each bar doesn't appear in the middle of the bar. This happen with Firefox and Chrome but with a little difference between them.

The code executed to set the text in the middle of the bar is the same:

```
bar
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(function(d) {
    return keys.map(function(key) {
      return {
        key: key,
        value: d[key]
      };
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("class", "label-half-donut")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return scales.x1Scale.bandwidth() * (i + 0.5);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return scales.yScale(d.value) - 5;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return lang === "es" ? String(d.value).replace(".", ",") + "%" : d.value + "%";
  });
```

The style applied is:

```
  .label-half-donut {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
```

In **Firefox** as you can see, the text over the bars are not in the middle of them:

[image]

And If we check the code in Firefox console, we've got these for the first two bars:

```
<text text-anchor="middle" class="label-half-donut" x="45" y="55">80,00%</text>
<text text-anchor="middle" class="label-half-donut" x="135" y="27">89,47%</text>
```

As you can see the attribute "text-anchor" is defined but doesn't work in Firefox.

In Chrome, happens the same but with a little difference. Here is a screencap where you can see that the text is not in the middle of the bar.

[image]

As you can see the width of the graphic is a little bit bigger than in Firefox. So, this could be the reason of why is not equal the position of the text than in Firefox. But, dispite of this, the text still isn't centered.

Here you can see the code that we've got in Chrome console:

```
<text text-anchor="middle" class="label-half-donut" x="59.5" y="55">80,00%</text>
<text text-anchor="middle" class="label-half-donut" x="178.5" y="27">89,47%</text>
```

In this code, as like before, there is the attribute "text-anchor" but this doesn't work correctly.

Is there any way to center the text correctly independt of the web browser and the width of it? Exists the possibility to make this text "responsibility"?
Am I doin'g somethin wrong when I define the text over the bar chart?

**EDIT I:**

Here you've got an example of the code:
[image: Edit MultipleBarChart]

But here, the text is correctly centered, not in my web application where the code is exactly the same.

Comment: Would you mind providing a complete example, including the code positioning the bars? a stack snippet would be perfect for this. [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @Mehdi!!! I have updated my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code which works in CodeSandbox and does not work in your app, from previous experience it could be the inherited CSS properties. In your case your text labels acquire most properties from `.label-half-donut`, however it acquires `text-align` property from somewhere else.

Hence I suggest to try adding that to your .label-half-donut and add `text-anchor: middle` as well as a failsafe

```
.label-half-donut {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: end;
    text-anchor: middle;
}
```

Comment: OMG!!! It works!!! Thank you for your appreciated help!!! You have save me twice!!! :) Next time, I will check if there is any inherited CSS propery which make doesn't work fine my development!!! Thanks!!!